# jQuery Mobile swipe to "nothing"

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, touch, responsive-design

I found another SO question that had a fiddle with similar functionality to what I'm trying to do.  Instead of swiping to a new div however I would like to simply slide the div off the screen

http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
});
```

The div in question is actually a jQuery UI dialog, $("#div").dialog({...});.  I would like to simply swipe it off the screen and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#home').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $("#listitem").bind('swiperight',function(event, ui){
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1", { transition: "slide", reverse: true});
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UaupV/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about a popup you can do stuff like this :

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.animate({
        right: '-999px'
    }, 'slow', function() {
        t.remove();
    })
});​
```

Comment: Thats what im currently doing.  Very choppy.  I ended up using CSS transitions

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
```

});

​And point page to to a blank page

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/2810/)